# Extract data from dynamic HTML Table with Python 3

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, lxml

I've been working on a python 3 script to generate BibTeX entries, and have [ISSN's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Serial_Number) that I would like to use to get information regarding the associated Journal.

For instance, I would like to take the ISSN `0897-4756` and find that this is `Chemistry of Materials` journal, which is published by `ACS Publications`.

I can do this manually using [this site](https://www.journalguide.com/journals/search?type=journal-name&journal-name=), where the info that I am looking for is stored in the lxml table `//table[@id="journal-search-results-table"]`, or more specifically, in the cells of the table body thereof.

I have, however, not been able to get this to automate successfully using python 3.x

I have attempted to access the data using approaches from the `httplib2`, `requests`, `urllib2`, and `lxml.html` packages, with no success thusfar.

What I have so far is shown below:

```py
import certifi       
import lxml.html
import urllib.request

ISSN = "0897-4756"
address = "https://www.journalguide.com/journals/search?type=journal-name&journal-name={}".format(ISSN)

hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
  'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
  'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
  'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
  'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
  'Connection': 'keep-alive'}

request = urllib.request.Request(address,None,hdr)  #The assembled request
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
html = response.read()
tree = lxml.html.fromstring(html)

print(tree.xpath('//table[@id="journal-search-results-table"]/text()'))
# >> ['\n', '\n']
# Shows that I am connecting to the table

print(tree.xpath('//table[@id="journal-search-results-table"]//td/text()'))
# >> []
# Should???? hold the data segments that I am looking for?
```

[Exact page being queryed by the above](https://www.journalguide.com/journals/search?type=journal-name&journal-name=0897-4756)

From what I can tell, it would appear that the table's `tbody` element, and thus the `tr` and `td` elements that it contains are not being loaded at the time that python is interpretting the HTML - which is accordingly preventing me from reading the data.

**How do I make it so that I can read out the Journal Name and Publisher from the specified table above?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you mentioned in your question, this table dynamically changes by `javascript`. To get around this you actually have to render the `javascript` using:

- A web driver like [selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) which simulates a website the same way it would look to the user (by rendering the javascript)
- [requests-html](https://requests.readthedocs.io/projects/requests-html/en/latest/), which is a relatively new module that allows you to render `javascript` on a webpage and has a lot of other amazing features for web scraping

This is one way to solve your problem using requests-html:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

ISSN = "0897-4756"
address = "https://www.journalguide.com/journals/search?type=journal-name&journal-name={}".format(ISSN)

hdr = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive'
}

ses = HTMLSession()
response = ses.get(address, headers=hdr)
response.html.render() # render the javascript to load the elements in the table
tree = response.html.lxml # no need to import lxml.html because requests-html can do this for you

print(tree.xpath('//table[@id="journal-search-results-table"]/text()'))
# >> ['\n', '\n']

print(tree.xpath('//table[@id="journal-search-results-table"]//td/text()'))
# >> ['ACS Publications', '1.905', 'No', '\n', '\n', '\n']
```